# Is there some way to "hook into" PHP's "echo" mechanism?

Tags: php, echo

For a long time now, I have had my own wrapper function around `echo`, so that instead of:

```
echo 'This is an example.';
```

I do (in CLI scripts):

```
terminal_output('This is an example.');
```

This allows me to, for example, do fancy outputting of the text on the terminal. For example, I can make it look like it's "typed out" with random delays.

Sometimes, I realize that I have been using "echo" instead of my wrapper function, and then I have to sit and change them all into my function calls.

It strikes me that, maybe, there is some way to "hook into" the `echo` function so that I can indeed use `echo` everywhere, yet do any kind of fancy processing I feel like? And of course, that wrapper function would check whether it's in `web` or `cli` mode, and always directly output if in `web` mode.

I've oftentimes found hidden "gems" like this in PHP which are barely documented or well hidden, so maybe it's the case this time as well?

Comment: Take a look at [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I know about those functions (but they have always been scary)... Not sure how you mean it's relevant to this, though?

Comment: You want to use `echo`, but have some control over how it performs. You can't intercept `echo`, but you can buffer the output for later retrieval. When you retrieve the buffer you can do what you want with it. You can retrieve the buffer as frequently as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Functions can be [namespaced](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php). PHP native functions can be redefined with the same name in custom namespaces.

But [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is a special case. It is not a function, but is a language construct.

```php
// echo supports non-function-shape calls since it's a language construct.
echo "string", "string";
```

AKAIK, the language may not allow you to define a function with that name.